# Adobe flex convert ".ogg" file with Ogg Vorbis Encoder for being played with Sound class

Tags: apache-flex, audio, encoding, ogg, oggvorbis

I'm trying to get a ".ogg" file from an URL and play it in my Flex program.

I've make a test with ".mp3" files and it works all fine, with this code:

```
        public function getFileRemote(url:String, id:String):void{
            var s:Sound = new Sound();
            s.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded);
            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);   
            s.load(req);

        }

        private function onSoundLoaded(event:Event):void
        {
            var localSound:Sound = event.target as Sound;
            localSound.play();
        }
```

But, for ".ogg" format files it doesn't work. So, I've checked some possible solutions and I'm, trying to implement one with the [Ogg Vorbis Encoder library](http://labs.byhook.com/2011/02/22/ogg-vorbis-encoder-decoder-for-flash/).

The code as I have it right now implemented:

```
        public function getFileRemote(url:String, id:String):void  
        {  
            urlStream = new URLStream();
            var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);  
            urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);  
            urlStream.load (urlReq);
        }  

        private function handleSoundData(e:SampleDataEvent):void
        {//handleSoundData
            var result:Object;
            var tmpBuffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            result = _oggManager.getSampleData(NUM_SAMPLES, tmpBuffer);

            if (tmpBuffer.length < NUM_SAMPLES * BYTES_PER_SAMPLE)
            {//reset
                trace("Reset");
                //Right now the only way to rewind is reseting the decoder
                _oggManager.initDecoder(_oggBytes);
                result = _oggManager.getSampleData( NUM_SAMPLES, tmpBuffer);
            }//reset

            tmpBuffer.position = 0; 
            while (tmpBuffer.bytesAvailable)
            {//feed
                //feed data
                e.data.writeFloat(tmpBuffer.readFloat());       //Left Channel
                e.data.writeFloat(tmpBuffer.readFloat());       //Right Channel
            }//feed

        }//handleSoundData

        private function loaded(event:Event):void  
        {  
            urlStream.readBytes(_oggBytes, 0, urlStream.bytesAvailable);
            //urlStream.readBytes(_oggBytes);
            _oggManager.decode(_oggBytes);
            //_oggManager.initDecoder(_oggBytes);
            //Make sound
            _sound = new Sound();
            _sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, handleSoundData, false, 0, true);
            _soundChannel = _sound.play();
            //trace(urlLoader.data);
        }  */
```

In the fucntion **loaded()**, either with both encodings:

- _oggManager.decode(_oggBytes);
- _oggManager.initDecoder(_oggBytes);

I get this error:

```
Main Thread (Suspended: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.) 
    es.maubic.oxford.portal.views.sessions::ListAudiosView/loaded
```

So, any tips? any other possible solutions?

**UPDATE**

Finally, I chose another solution. 
I rejected transforming ogg audio to mp3.
Instead of that, now the ogg audios are in a server and I only need the URL to play them through an audio html tag in my MainApp.html file. Simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Where is `_oggManager` defined?  It looks like that's null in the `loaded` function.

Comment: @Brian sorry mate, I've just updated the question because I found an alternative solution to the problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Post your solution!  It might be helpful to someone later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've founded an alternative solution to the problem in the question.

Instead of convert the *.ogg* file into a *.mp3* file, I've modified my code in order to reproduce directly in the application the *.ogg* file from its url (where it's stored in a server).

Adding this code to main app ***html*** file (in my case *Admin.html*):

```
    <audio id="audioOgg">
         <source src='' type='audio/ogg'>
    </audio>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        var media = document.getElementById("audioOgg");
        var cp=document.getElementById("Admin");
        var audioId;
        function playAudio(audioURL, id) {
            media.src = audioURL;
            audioId = id;
            media.play();
            cp.onStartAudio(audioId);
        }
        function pauseAudio() {
            media.pause();
        }
    </script>
```

And this code to in the ***.mxml*** file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <mx:TitleWindow xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" title="Audio List" 
                horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="auto" width="510" height="340" 
                showCloseButton="true" close="closeWindow()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            [Embed(source='../assets/play-btn-small.png')]
            var Play:Class;
            [Embed(source='../assets/stop-btn-small.png')]
            var Stop:Class;

            [Blindable]
            public var dpc:ArrayCollection;

            public function playAudio(audioURL:String, audioId:String){
                ExternalInterface.call("playAudio", audioURL, id);
            }

            public function pauseAudio(){
                ExternalInterface.call("pauseAudio");   
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Rotate id="rotate" />
    <mx:Zoom id="zoom" />
    <mx:VBox top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0" paddingTop="20" paddingLeft="20">
        <mx:Text fontWeight="bold" height="20">
            <mx:text>Click the play/pause button for listening/pause each audio individually:</mx:text>
        </mx:Text>
    </mx:VBox>
    <mx:DataGrid id="gridAudios" top="50" bottom="20" left="20" right="20" width="100%" doubleClickEnabled="false">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Name" dataField="audioId"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn id="btnCol" headerText="" textAlign="center">
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <mx:Component>
                        <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="center">
                            <mx:Script>
                                <![CDATA[
                                    protected function image1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                                    {
                                        if (data.status=='playing'){
                                            outerDocument.pauseAudio(); 
                                            data.status='';
                                        }else{
                                            outerDocument.playAudio(data.url,data.audioId);
                                            data.status='playing';
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]]>
                            </mx:Script>

                            <mx:Image click="image1_clickHandler(event)" 
                                      toolTip="{data.status=='playing' ? 'Stop' : 'Play'}"
                                      useHandCursor="true" source="{data.status=='playing' ? outerDocument.Stop : outerDocument.Play}"/>
                        </mx:HBox>
                    </mx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:TitleWindow>
```

Thanks to the ***ExternalInterface*** class I'm able to call the Javascript functions declared in my Admin.html file in order to reproduce and stop the audio of the  tag element, passing as arguments the audio url & the audio identificator.

Comment: If this is the answer to your own question, please, mark it as correct answer. Cheers!